# Test exited due to SIGKILL

Tags: travis-ci, ava

One of my ava tests has suddenly started failing on Travis CI, because it "exited due to SIGKILL". The first broken run can be found at https://travis-ci.org/freaktechnik/justintv-stream-notifications/builds/259734700#L471

The changes for that commit only affected modules loaded by that module and the tests still pass on my local machine. The change added another module to the hierarchy.

I'm wondering if the process could get killed due to too much memory use or similar, as I am using babel to precompile the tested files at ava runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limiting the amount of test files ava executes at once to 10 not only solved this problem, but also made the build a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, it looks like a out of memory issue.

An easy/cheap of getting more memory on travis is by using `dist: trusty` and `sudo: required`. It expands the maximum memory available from 4GB to 7.5GB [travis source](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/precise/). Scheduling on the opensource travis-ci.org can be a little bit slower due to the container overhead though

Comment: I've found a better solution by just limitting the amount of precesses from ava which still allows me to run inside the container infrastructure and is actually slightly faster.